# Magstrip font doesn't print correctly from PDF

Tags: css, pdf, printing, fonts

I've been racking my brain and the internet for an answer, but the best reason I can come up with is "font subsetting":

We've got a card printer at work that we use to create ID cards. The cards have a magstripe so users can swipe and do photocopying and such. Our current software is very lacking in features, so I'm writing my own in node.js. Because the magstripe is essentially a font (that is, I can go into Microsoft Word, pick "Track 2" as the font, and print a card with an encoded magnetic stripe), I figured this would be easy enough to do.

I'm using EJS to create the card in HTML (using CSS web fonts to load the TTF) and PhantomJS to save it as a PDF. The resulting card looks great, and when I view the properties of the card (via File > Properties in Adobe Acrobat Pro), I can see the font has been successfully embedded:

[image: The embedded font]

And when I edit the text object on the card, I can see the font is there:

[image: The font when I edit the text object]

But when I print, the magstripe is not encoded. The font is installed on my PC (as it's the same PC that does the printing), so I'm not sure why. As I said in my opening paragraph, I suspect it has something to do with a subset of the font being embedded, but from what I can tell, this shouldn't be an issue.

I then went in to Microsoft Word, created a document, then saved it as a PDF. I now get this message when trying to edit the text object:

[image: Error when editing the object]

Followed by this font:

[image: Fonts shown when editing the text object on a PDF created in Word]

However printing this document does NOT write the magstripe (but printing from Word directly DOES)

So I have two questions:

1) Why isn't this printing?

2) If it won't print no matter what, how can I generate a PDF (or another document) that will print correctly? Outputting to a printable file is a *must* because at the start of the year I have ~1000 cards to print (as they have the current year on them)

**EDIT:** I just went into a document that doesn't have the font in it at all, edited the text object, then looked for the Track 2 font in the list of available fonts. I can only see Track 1 and Track NTT (different tracks for different systems -- we need Track 2). The font is definitely installed, because trying to install it again tells me it's already installed, plus I can print from Word just fine.

[image: No Track 2 listed]

**EDIT 2:** Here's [a gist containing my code](https://gist.github.com/Grayda/cb4064e46c06cd9a924d81acf2752145), a [final card](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7qgo6_VU2XRTEM2R0MwdHIyRzQ/view?usp=sharing) and a [Word document with that font, converted straight to PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7qgo6_VU2XRWUJvVDZ4NVZkSTg/view?usp=sharing) with a final card and a test Word -> PDF document.

The final card is upside down because the printer prints upside down. I've also tried rotating the whole PDF and such to see if it's an orientation thing, and copying the font into my project folder and using `src()` to load it but it doesn't seem to work either way

Comment: I may have overread it, but which version of Acrobat Pro are you using?

Comment: @MaxWyss Acrobat X (v10.1.13 to be specific)

Comment: I personally did not have good experience with fonts and editing PDF in Acrobat until Acrobat DC; you might therefore try Acrobat DC and see if you can access the font.

Comment: Do you have an example PDF file so we could see how the font is embedded in the PDF file you created?

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche I've updated my question to include links to my code, a "final" PDF, and a PDF exported straight from Word

Comment: For most card printers, the magstripe font is a placeholder. When the card printer driver sees text using this font, it sends the text to the magstripe encoder instead of rendering the text. When Acrobat sends data from the PDF to the card printer driver, it may not be mapping the TrueType font to the card printer device font correctly.  If you can tell us more about the card printer model, we can investigate the name of the magstripe device font and compare it to the TrueType font name.

Comment: @CraigLebakken That makes a ton of sense, actually. The printer is a [Datacard CP40 Plus](https://www.datacard.com/id-card-printer-support-and-drivers/cp40-plus-card-printer. I suspect it'd be much the same for the other printers in the DataCard range.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Actually, this is causing issues too. I guess the the document is being sent as something that the printer is unable to inspect and look for the font or escape codes. Back to the drawing board it is!

---

This isn't an answer to the specific problem, where font doesn't survive the transition to PDF, but I have come up with a solution for my general problem (not being able to encode anything to a card I've created).

My solution was to turn on [Magstripe Escape Code Compatibility](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/831478/Datacard-Magna.html?page=168#manual) in the advanced printer properties, then use one of the escape codes to write the data.

[image]

Specifically, I had to use this kind of escape code:

`~2%123456?`

With `~2` indicating the track number, `%` indicating the start of the sequence to encode, and `?` to end the sequence.

I'm not going to mark this as the answer, because I'm keen to know why the font wasn't working in PDF, but for anyone else who comes across a similar issue and needs a fix, this is it.